# TCPDF Costum header image error

Tags: php, tcpdf

I keep getting the same error when I try to add a custom header image with TCPDF

```
$pdf->SetHeaderData("logo.png", PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, "Something", "Lorem Ipsum");
```

It tells me:

```
TCPDF ERROR: Can't open image file: /var/www/tcpdf/cache/mska_93170920eb930db72b109d6a0f192715
```

I'm on Ubuntu, what should I do?

**UPDATE**: Okay, it seems tcpdf has some trouble with png images, used jpg instead and it worked!

Comment: Is logo.png in your script's current working directory? Is it readable by PHP?

Comment: @MarcB Its in tcpdf's default image directory. I get a different error when tcpdf can't find the original image. It seems tcpdf can't copy logo.png to to its cache folder